# Is there a way I can pool together 3 variables based on conditions into a new column?

Tags: r

I am dealing with survey data, and there are 30 questions in sets of 10, where each question from each set corresponds to the same question from another set, e.g. D5a_1, D5b_1, D5c_1 are all the same except for the addition or removal of a specific word. I am to pool such questions together into a new column to run a regression (going with the example: D5a_1,D5b_1,D5c_1 as D5_1).
the values range from 1 (selected), 0 (not selected), -77 (skipped).
How should I approach this?

Comment: Share some sample input (reproducibly, preferably using `dput()` so class an structure info are included and it's copy/pasteable), and the corresponding desired output. Just 5-10 rows to illustrate the problem.

Comment: For example, `dput(your_data[1:10, c("ID", "D5a_1", "D5b_1", "D5c_1", ....)])`, including perhaps one more set of 3 columns.